# Integration Response Phase is Disabled in AWS Api gateway, unable to change integration response?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Integration Response Phase is Disabled in AWS Api gateway, unable to change integration response.
how to get it enabled ?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Proxy check box, It will be enabled.
still the AWSProxyRequest, response will work.

Comment: How to do this ?